# i can't posting data from view to another view using reverse and HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: django, cleaned-data

i'm trying to sending data from a submitted form to another view in my app but

## forms.py

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Currency_choices)
    continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_continent())   
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_country())
```

## views.py

view #1

```
def filtrer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            currency = form.cleaned_data['currency']
            continent = form.cleaned_data['continent']
            country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            url = reverse('affiche_filter', args=(), kwargs={'continent':continent,'country':country,'currency':currency})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form =FilterForm()
    return render_to_response('filter.html', {'form': form }, RequestContext(request))
```

view#2

```
def affiche_filter(request,continent, country,currency):

    data = Select_WHERE(continent, country, currency)
    symbol = ConvertSymbol(currency)   
    return render_to_response('affiche_continent.html', {'data': data,'symbol':symbol }, RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myform.views',                 
                       url(r'^filtrer$', 'filtrer'),
                       url(r'^affiche_filter/(?P<continent>[-\w]+)/(?P<country>[-\w]+)/(?P<currency>[-\w]+)/$', 'affiche_filter', name='affiche_filter'),
```

seems that the method "form.cleaned_data" return key of the selected value in my choicefield not the the value itself
this what i got after submitted my form

[image: This error is showed because the third parameter(here is'0') calculating the rate should be USD OR EURO not '0']

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace that accompanies the error?

Comment: what's `Select_WHERE`?

Comment: Select_Where is SQL Request retrieving data with the a specific value of(continent,country and currency) getted from Filter View when POSTing
the problem is that clean-data do not return the selected value of choicefield but the key

Comment: What are your choices? Which choicefield is causing the problem? What are the values of `continent` `country` `currency` when the second view is run? The problem you have outlined in the questions doesn't match what you think the issue is (an problem with a form field)

Comment: i get my choices from my DB(retrieving all continents,countries,currencies exists in my DB) and when submitting my form and having a POST request i want to send this selected values of my 3 choicefields(i used form.cleaned_data in 'Filtrer' view but it didn't return values but keys) to the other view 'affiche_filter'

Comment: the question is how can i get the selected values of the choicefield from my form and send it to other view ?

Comment: I don't know why you posted a picture of the traceback rather than the actual traceback. As far as I can see via squinting, though, the error is happening inside `Select_WHERE`. So maybe, perhaps, you might consider posting the code to that function?